# derivatives using basic differentiation find f'

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

$f(x) = 3x^2 \sqrt[3] x$

For my  answer i keep getting $6x \sqrt[3] x$ + x 4/3

I feel as if I am very wrong someone please help

Comment: Your expression for $f(x)$ ia ambiguous!

Comment: ? please help me

Comment: Note that $x^2 \sqrt[3]x = x^2 x^{1/3} = x^{2+1/3} = x^{7/3}$. Apply the power rule.

Comment: Can you describe this in any more detail please I'm lost

Comment: no sorry I'm trying to teach this to myself

Comment: would you be able to show by any chance how to do that because i’m not sure where those values enter